# How can I add a custom intrinsic in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am new to LLVM. I have added a custom intrinsic *foo_sqrt* by creating *IntrinsicsFoo.td* in *include/llvm/IR/*. I then built the entire llvm project and the intrinsic *foo* has been added successfully (*foo_sqrt* has been added to the *Intrinsic* namespace). But I am unable to figure out how to add the pseudo instruction for it so that *Intrinsic::getDeclaration()* function will work inside my pass. If I want my intrinsic *foo* to calculate the square root of a floating point number, where should I add this instruction? I have searched a lot on the Internet and couldn't find anything concrete. 
Here is the content of the td file:

```
let TargetPrefix = "foo" in { // All intrinsics start with "llvm.foo."
def int_foo_sqrt : GCCBuiltin<"__builtin_foo_sqrt">,
                    Intrinsic<[llvm_anyfloat_ty], [llvm_anyfloat_ty],
                              [IntrNoMem]>;
} // end TargetPrefix
```